# How can I add a vertical bar | to a table on the site?

Tags: support, formatting

Earlier today, I posted an answer where I needed to add a table. But this table needed to have the vertical line character (|) in one of its cells. But I wasn't able to add it to the cell since it would think that it's supposed to be a part of the table!

This is what the table roughly looks like (there's a vertical line in the "Symbol" column) :

| Text | Symbol |
| --- | --- |
| Vertical bar |  |

This is exactly what is in the Markdown :

```
| Text | Symbol |
| -------- | -------- |
| Vertical bar | | |
```

And even if I try putting quotes around it :

| Text | Symbol |
| --- | --- |
| Vertical bar | “ |

```
| Text | Symbol |
| -------- | -------- |
| Vertical bar | “|“ |
```

<sub>Other thing weird with the above one : it only shows on of the two quotes (apparently the one before the vertical bar I'm trying to show (boldened here : **“**|“).</sub>

---

It just seems that there's no way to add a vertical line to a table.

Is this possible? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe with a backslash -> `\|`.

| Text | Symbol |
| --- | --- |
| Vertical bar | | |

There is a help function in the editor menu at right (the question mark) which will lead you to the way tables are defined and from there to the Github page with all the details.